# Integrate Python Projects Into Xcode

Tags: python, xcode, native

I'm a Mac user, and one of my hobbies is programming. I use Xcode, the integrated IDE of Mac OS X. I started to learn Python programming langage, and I want to use Xcode for developing my scripts. I searched for weeks in the internet, but I didn't find something interesting.

Firstly, I want to update the integrated interpreter of Mac OS X, that is on 2.6 version. And secondly, I want to create a Python project on Xcode easily, like I do with C & C++ projects.

Can you help me? I really need help! Cordially.

Comment: See http://wiki.python.org/moin/MacPython/XcodeIntegration

Comment: Thank you, but this informations are quite obsolete (the screens are from a Mac OS 9 system I guess). Also, I saw this page before, but thanks anyway. :)

Comment: @user528474 Which Xcode Version do you use?